# How to get user input like editText then insert to database sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I want to get user input like editText when click save button insert to sqlite database.  How to make that. I'm searching but I can't find it. I'm coding a notepad app.  Reference [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qyehP.png)

```
    package com.suleymanemre.notepad;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class note extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note);

        button= findViewById(R.id.save);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);

    }
    public void save(View view){
        SQLiteDatabase noteDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("Notes",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

        noteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notes(Notes VARCHAR);");

    }

    public void esc (View view){
        super.onBackPressed(); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prepare a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

This link might be helpful for creating memo app.

https://www.javahelps.com/2015/07/android-memo-application.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just save 1 value consider using SharedPreference using:

```
SharedPreference mPref = context.getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//get value
 return mPref.getString(Key.YOUR_KEY, DEFAULT_VALUE_IN_STRING);
//add value
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mPref.edit();
mEditor.putString(Key.YOUR_KEY, YOUR_VALUE);
mEditor.commit()
```

If you want to use SQLite Database, Consider using Room:

Add this to your build.gradle file:

```
def room_version = "2.2.5"

  implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
  annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Create your database classes:

```
@androidx.room.Dao
public interface MyDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM MyClass")
    List<MyClass> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insertAll(List<MyClass> mList);

    @Insert
    void insert(MyClass mItem);
}
```

Create your App Database Class:

```
@Database(entities = {MyClass.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class MyAppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract MyDao MyDao();
}
```

Create your Singleton class:

```
public class MyDatabaseClient {

    private Context mCtx;
    private static MyDatabaseClient mInstance;

    private MyAppDatabase myAppDatabase;

    private MyDatabaseClient(Context mCtx) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        myAppDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(mCtx, MyClass.class, "MyDatabaseName").build();
    }

    public static synchronized MyDatabaseClient getInstance(Context mCtx) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MyDatabaseClient(mCtx);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public MyAppDatabase getMyAppDatabase() {
        return myAppDatabase;
```

Your item class (feel free to add new items to save or retrieve:

```
@Entity
public class MyClass implements Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "uid")
    public int uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String name;

    public int getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(int uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Usage:

```
//Get All
MyDatabaseClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getMyAppDatabase().MyDao().getAll();

//Insert
final List<MyClass> mList = new ArrayList<>();
MyClass items = new MyClass();
items.setName("YOUR_VALUE");
mList.add(items);
MyDatabaseClient.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getMyAppDatabase().MyDao().insertAll(mList);
```

Comment: Im newbie programming.I dont understand.Why you write <myclass>.Im confused.Should i watch room database tutorial.

Comment: myclass is just a name. You can use any name like ItemsClass or UserInputClass